# PrestoDB -- Select rows where varchar column is in array query

Tags: sql, arrays, presto, trino

I have data that looks as follows

```
WITH dataset AS (
    SELECT *
    FROM (
             VALUES (1, "foo"]),
                    (2, "bar")
         ) AS t (ID, Column1))
SELECT
    ID, 
    Column1
FROM
    dataset
```

and I want to add a `WHERE` clause that finds rows that have values in an array `["bar", "baz", "zap"]`

something like the pseudo-code `WHERE Column1 in ARRAY["bar", "baz", "zap"]` which in this case would only return the second row.

I know that if `Column1` were a numerical column I could use `WHERE Column1 >= 12` but how do I do it for a column of type `varchar`?

Comment: Just `contains(ARRAY['bar', 'baz', 'zap'], column1)`? https://prestodb.io/docs/current/functions/array.html#contains

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on description it seems that simple [`IN`](https://prestodb.io/docs/current/sql/select.html#in) should be sufficient;

```sql
-- sample data
WITH dataset(ID, Column1) AS (
   VALUES (1, 'foo'),
        (2, 'bar')
)

-- query
SELECT *
FROM
    dataset
WHERE Column1 in ('bar', 'baz', 'zap');
```

Output:

| ID | Column1 |
| --- | --- |
| 2 | bar |

If you have an array for example stored in another column then use [`contains`](https://prestodb.io/docs/current/functions/array.html#contains):

```sql
-- sample data
WITH dataset(ID, Column1, arr) AS (
   VALUES (1, 'foo', array['foo1']),
        (2, 'bar', array['foo1', 'bar'])
)

-- query 
SELECT
    ID,
    Column1
FROM
    dataset
WHERE contains(arr, Column1);
```